# Trigger to insert tupples to a table for each row in another table after insert on a third table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have three table council_member, mess and rates.

```
council_member(student_id, field2,...)
mess(mess_id,field2,...)
rates(student_id,mess_id,rating)
```

student_id and mess_id are foreign keys.

Rates stores the rating for each mess by each council member. I want to create a trigger that on insertion of a new council member, inserts tupples to the table rates for the inserted student_id and each mess_id in mess with a rating of 10.

How do I run the insert statement in trigger for each mess_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works great

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_council_member 
AFTER INSERT ON council_member
FOR EACH ROW 
  INSERT INTO rates SELECT NEW.student_id, mess_id, 10 FROM mess;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac4a0/1